# What is the intent of inline <?=$GLOBAL?> directive in PHP? Is it markdown?

Tags: php, syntax, tags, markdown, encryption

I am working on a [PHP project](https://github.com/nst/Quickies) that is using an (anti)-convention that is causing errors, and I'm not quite sure what it is trying to achieve, so fixing it is difficult..

The project does use markdown, which I have included at runtime… But I can't find mention of this syntax anywhere, [including the extended documentation](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/), so, here I am.. Any ideas as to what is this syntax trying to accomplish?

It doesn't help that the original developer used short tags (don't do that, people).. but here goes..  It is the `<?=$PHP_SELF?>` that is causing problems..

```
<p>[<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">categories</a>] 
       [<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?index">index</a>] 
       [<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?all">all (<?=$notes_count?>)</a>] 
       [<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?latest">latest</a>]</p>
```

Comment: Is `$PHP_SELF` being localized from `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, if not then that might be the issue.

Comment: What problem? What errors? I can't tell whether you know what short_tags _are_ or not. You seem to understand them and also not understand them. And I don't know why Markdown would suddenly be involved in PHP syntax.

Comment: For interest's sake: `<?=` as shorthand for echo will always be enabled come PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: I've always had short tag support (`<? ?>` ) turned off... So was just trying to "seperate" the command from the `<?`.  I am running PHP 5.4, so that's good to know about `<?=`.  (That particular combiation of characters is ungoogleable - and returns no hits on SE, either..)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorthand for:

```
<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>
```

Your method would work if `short_open_tag` is enabled in your php.ini, but will cause errors otherwise.

Presumably, the `$PHP_SELF` variable has been initialized prior to these usages, possibly as a duplicate of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. If it has not been initialized, you may want to update your code to reference `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

Comment: I think it should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`, and that's _even if_ you keep this horrible intrusive PHP output.

Comment: Either way is correct. When you use <?= it is the shortcut syntax for echoing variables. http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Only with short_tags enabled, which it should not be if you are a sane person.

Comment: I suppose that was an assumption on my part considering OP's original code used short tags.

Comment: My point is that "it should be <insert any code with short_tags in them here>" is wrong :)

Comment: The only reason I'm even being confronted by this is because I refuse to enable short tags, so I was trying to "divorce" the opening tag from the command..  I actually thought my Find and Replace had gone afoul when I first saw it...